# oneshot systemd unit is enabled and “wantedby”, but not started

Tags: debian, boot, service, systemd

I wrote the following systemd unit, in `/etc/systemd/system/regen-ssh-keys.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Server Key Generation

# Do not run if keys already exist
ConditionPathExistsGlob=!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key

# This service requires rng-tools to feed the random number generator,
# otherwise we may generate predictable keys without noticing it.
Requires=rng-tools.service
After=rng-tools.service

# sshd needs this service to be run and finished before starting
PartOf=sshd.service sshd.socket
Before=sshd.service sshd.socket

[Install]
# sshd needs this service to be run and finished before starting
WantedBy=sshd.service sshd.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

and I enabled it with `systemctl enable regen-ssh-keys`.

It is not started at boot or when ssh starts, although `service regen-ssh-keys status` tells me it is loaded and enabled, and “inactive (dead)”. 
Also, it is not listed by `systemctl -a`.

However, when I start it manually with `service regen-ssh-keys start`, it starts as expected.

Did I do something wrong when writing the unit?

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? CentOS already has a systemd unit which generates ssh keys, for instance, and it actually works. Try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Debian Stretch. If you know of an (easier) alternative to this, I would be happy to use it.

Comment: Eh? Even Debian ought to have such a unit already present.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't find any doc mentioning it

Comment: I suggest that you go looking for it. The openssh server would not come up at all if the keys had not already been generated, which means something already on the system must have done so.

Comment: Debian generates host keys when installing the package; and one can regenerate them using `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`. However, I'm building a distributable image, so I want it to generate keys on first boot.

Comment: Hm. I guess I'll add this to the ever-growing list of Debian design flaws. In the meantime I suggest you grab a nearby Fedora or CentOS system and look at its unit files for how it should be done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was simply that I did not use the right names for the SSH service. Replacing `sshd.service sshd.socket` by `ssh.service ssh.socket` fixed the issue.